# Angular 2. Не отображаются данные в Tree компоненте

Tags: angular2

Подскажите, почему не отображаются данные в моем Tree компоненте. Я пытаюсь использовать [PrimeNG tree](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree). Ошибок нету, не могу понять в чем проблема. Мой код:

**node.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TreeNode} from "primeng/primeng";

@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

  getFiles(): TreeNode[] {
    return [
        {
            "data":
                [
                    {
                        "label": "Documents",
                        "data": "Documents Folder",
                        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                        "children": [{
                            "label": "Work",
                            "data": "Work Folder",
                            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                            "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
                        },
                            {
                                "label": "Home",
                                "data": "Home Folder",
                                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                                "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
                            }]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Pictures",
                        "data": "Pictures Folder",
                        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                        "children": [
                            {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
                            {"label": "logo.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
                            {"label": "primeui.png", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Movies",
                        "data": "Movies Folder",
                        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                        "children": [{
                            "label": "Al Pacino",
                            "data": "Pacino Movies",
                            "children": [{"label": "Scarface", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Scarface Movie"}, {"label": "Serpico", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Serpico Movie"}]
                        },
                            {
                                "label": "Robert De Niro",
                                "data": "De Niro Movies",
                                "children": [{"label": "Goodfellas", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Goodfellas Movie"}, {"label": "Untouchables", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Untouchables Movie"}]
                            }]
                    }
                ]
        }
    ];
}
```

}

**period.tree.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Tree, TreeNode} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {NodeService} from './node.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'period-tree',
   template: `
       <p-tree [value]="files"></p-tree>
   `,
directives: [Tree],
providers: [NodeService]
})
export class PeriodTree implements OnInit {
    files: TreeNode[];
    constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.files = this.nodeService.getFiles();
    }
}
```

**period.modal.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PeriodTree} from '../app.tree/period.tree';

@Component({
    selector: 'period-modal',
    template:`
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" style="height: 550px;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:#fff">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Изменить период (05/2016)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <period-tree></period-tree>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-right: 550px;">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ок</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`,
directives: [PeriodTree]
})
export class PeriodModal {}
```

А уже непосредственно period.modal.ts я подключаю как блок в нужное для меня место в контенте

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {LocalStorageService, LocalStorageSubscriber} from 'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter';
import {NodeService} from './app.tree/node.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ LocalStorageService, NodeService ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема, неправильно задавал данные. Правильно было бы так:
**node.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TreeNode} from "primeng/primeng";

@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

getFiles(): TreeNode[] {
    return [
        {
            "label": "Documents",
            "data": "Documents Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [{
                "label": "Work",
                "data": "Work Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
            }, 
                {
                    "label": "Home",
                    "data": "Home Folder",
                    "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                    "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                    "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
                }]
        },
        {
            "label": "Pictures",
            "data": "Pictures Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [
                {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
                {"label": "logo.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
                {"label": "primeui.png", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
        },
        {
            "label": "Movies",
            "data": "Movies Folder",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [{
                "label": "Al Pacino",
                "data": "Pacino Movies",
                "children": [{"label": "Scarface", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Scarface Movie"}, {"label": "Serpico", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Serpico Movie"}]
            },
                {
                    "label": "Robert De Niro",
                    "data": "De Niro Movies",
                    "children": [{"label": "Goodfellas", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Goodfellas Movie"}, {"label": "Untouchables", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Untouchables Movie"}]
                }]
        }


    ];
}
}
```